# plot each day of time series in a single plot in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I have one month of data as time series with `1 Hz` sampling frequency :

```
data <- data.frame(
  date = as.POSIXct("2019-01-01 12:00:00") - 0:2678399,
  value = runif(2678400) + seq(-140, 224,len = 2678400)^2 / 10000
)
```

How could I use ggplot to have one plot per day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
data = data %>% group_by(day = cut(date, "day"))

ggplot(data, aes(date,value),show.legend = FALSE) + 
      geom_point() +
      facet_wrap(~day, ncol = 5, scales = "free_x)
```

Comment: @AliHadjihosseini But what about x axis ? It keeps the entire month as X- axis range